# Possible race condition with ReactiveCocoa in MVVM app with Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, mvvm, reactive-cocoa

I have a demo application to show a possible race condition in the app I am working on. The app displays 2 UITextField: textField1 and textField2.

The following conditions applies:

- The textField1 string should be at least as long as the textField2 string.
- The textField2 string should not be longer than 5 characters.

The app uses MVVM pattern and Reactive Cocoa.

The app should save only valid configurations of textField1 and textField2.

**Entity.h**

```
@interface Entity : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name2;

@end
```

**ViewController.h**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ViewModel.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITextField *textField1;
@property(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITextField *textField2;

@property(nonatomic, strong) ViewModel *viewModel;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.viewModel = [[ViewModel alloc] init];

    // Two-way binding between  textfield1 and self.viewModel.name1
    // We cannot use a simple RACChannelTo = RACChannelTo because Textfield.text doesn't fire KVO notification on each strokes but only when exit the textfield.
    RACChannelTerminal *name1ModelTerminal = RACChannelTo(self, viewModel.name1);
    RAC(self.textField1, text) = name1ModelTerminal;
    [self.textField1.rac_textSignal subscribe:name1ModelTerminal];

    // Two-way binding between  textfield2 and self.viewModel.name2
    // We cannot use a simple RACChannelTo = RACChannelTo because Textfield.text doesn't fire KVO notification on each strokes but only when exit the textfield.
    RACChannelTerminal *name2ModelTerminal = RACChannelTo(self, viewModel.name2);
    RAC(self.textField2, text) = name2ModelTerminal;
    [self.textField2.rac_textSignal subscribe:name2ModelTerminal];

    // Validation
    RAC(self.textField1, backgroundColor) = [self.viewModel.name1IsValidSignal map:^id(NSNumber *value) {
        if ([value boolValue]) {
            return [UIColor clearColor];
        } else {
            return [UIColor redColor];
        }
    }];

    RAC(self.textField2, backgroundColor) = [self.viewModel.name2IsValidSignal map:^id(NSNumber *value) {
        if ([value boolValue]) {
            return [UIColor clearColor];
        } else {
            return [UIColor redColor];
        }
    }];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

**ViewModel.h**

```
#import "RVMViewModel.h"

@interface ViewModel : RVMViewModel

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *name1;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *name2;

@property(nonatomic, strong) RACSignal *name1IsValidSignal;
@property(nonatomic, strong) RACSignal *name2IsValidSignal;

@property(nonatomic, strong) RACSignal *isValidSignal;

@end
```

**ViewModel.m**

```
#import "ViewModel.h"
#import "Entity.h"

@interface ViewModel ()

@property(nonatomic, strong) Entity *model;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

@end

@implementation ViewModel

-(instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        [self initialize];
    }

    return self;
}

-(void)initialize {

    // setup Model
    self.managedObjectContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext];

    self.model = [Entity MR_createInContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    // log
    [RACObserve(self, name1) subscribeNext:^(NSString *name) {
        NSLog(@"viewModel.name1 = %@", name);
    }];

    [RACObserve(self, name2) subscribeNext:^(NSString *name) {
        NSLog(@"viewModel.name2 = %@", name);
    }];

    [RACObserve(self, model.name1) subscribeNext:^(NSString *name) {
        NSLog(@"model.name1 = %@", name);
    }];

    [RACObserve(self, model.name2) subscribeNext:^(NSString *name) {
        NSLog(@"model.name2 = %@", name);
    }];

    // Validation
    @weakify(self);
    self.name1IsValidSignal = [RACSignal combineLatest:@[RACObserve(self, name1),
                                                         RACObserve(self, name2)]
                                                reduce:^id(NSString *name1, NSString *name2) {
                                                    return @([name1 length] >= [name2 length]);
    }];

    self.name2IsValidSignal = [RACObserve(self, name2) map:^id(NSString *value) {
        return @([value length] < 6);
    }];

    self.isValidSignal = [[RACSignal combineLatest:@[self.name1IsValidSignal, self.name2IsValidSignal]] and];

    // Initial value of Model -> ViewModel
    self.name1 = self.model.name1;
    self.name2 = self.model.name2;

    // Binding: ViewModel -> Model when name is valid

    RAC(self, model.name1) = [[self.name1IsValidSignal filter:^BOOL(id value) {
        return [value boolValue];
    }] map:^id(id value) {
        @strongify(self);

        return self.name1;
    }];

    RAC(self, model.name2) = [[self.name2IsValidSignal filter:^BOOL(id value) {
        return [value boolValue];
    }] map:^id(id value) {
        @strongify(self);

        return self.name2;
    }];

    // Save with Core Data when both name1IsValidSignal and name2IsValidSignal returns @YES and that there are some unsaved changes in the context
    // There is a possible race condition here when this subscription is called before the bindings from ViewModel -> Model is called.
    [[[RACSignal combineLatest:@[RACObserve(self.managedObjectContext, hasChanges), self.isValidSignal]] and] subscribeNext:^(id x) {

        if ([x boolValue]) {
            // Save with Core Data
            [self.managedObjectContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                // TODO: error management
                if (success || !error) {
                    NSLog(@"Success");
                    NSLog(@" ");
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"Problem when saving to Core Data");
                }

            }];
        }
    }];
}

@end
```

From my point of view, it is possible that the save to Core Data in the last subscription in ViewModel.m happens before the model is updated. How do you prevent that to happen?

**EDIT**
What I really want is to push to Core Data model only configurations of (name1 and name2) that pass validation.

**Xcode Project**
https://github.com/guillaume-michel/ReactiveValidation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The race condition may be that name2IsValidSignal can be true before name1IsValidSignal is false. Which means that isValidSignal can be true momentarily before turning false (which would trigger the save). One solution is to combine the validation logic into a single unit:

```
    self.isValidSignal = [RACSignal combineLatest:@[RACObserve(self, name1),
                                                         RACObserve(self, name2)]
                                                reduce:^id(NSString *name1, NSString *name2) {
                                                    return @([name1 length] >= [name2 length] && [name2 length] < 6);
    }];
```

That should ensure that isValidSignal is only updated after all your validation logic has been run.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried what you said but the results is that is saves data to store that are not valid. For example, When the application launch, if I type a letter in textField 2, validation should says it is not valid but with your change it saves to store.

Comment: I updated the question with the link to a Github repository. You need Cocoapods.

Comment: When I start the application, I see an immediate save because you're not applying skip to the underlying RACObserve calls. After that the validation appears to work as expected. What are you trying to achieve? Are nil values acceptable? If so, then the behavior is as expected. If nil values aren't acceptable, you should update your signals to reflect that.

Comment: The first save is intentional. What I want to achieve is the following: The view model should keep the UI state in name1 and name2 properties and expose "is valid" signals to the view. The view model should put valid values to the model but only when they are valid. The model then has the last valid values. because we don't control the order the subscribers are called for a given signal, my guess is that I may run into a race condition where the values in the view model are not valid but the isValidSignal says otherwise leading to saving to the model invalid values.

Comment: OK, thanks for explaining. I misunderstood your original question. So the race condition can occur in the isValidSignal. It would be possible for the name2IsValidSignal to return true which would trigger an updated isValidSignal which would also return true and trigger the save. Immediately after this, name2IsValidSignal could turn false. However, you've already saved the result. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Your answer makes sense and I can use a doNext to update the model based on the validation status. The problem is i still need name1IsValidSignal and name2IsValidSignal in the ViewController to show the user which textfield is not valid. For that I can still use the original signals.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs for `-[NSManagedObjectContext hasChanges]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/hasChanges), you're not supposed to send messages to the NSManagedObjectContext synchronously with receiving a KVO notification:

> If you need to send messages to the context or change any of its managed objects as a result of a change to the value of hasChanges, you must do so after the call stack unwinds (typically using performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: or a similar method).

You could accomplish this in ReactiveCocoa by explicitly delivering to `+[RACScheduler mainThreadScheduler]`:

```
[[[[RACSignal combineLatest:@[RACObserve(self.managedObjectContext, hasChanges),
                              self.isValidSignal]]
             and]
             deliverOn:RACScheduler.mainThreadScheduler]
             subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    // ...
```